# How to use Facebook (GeoTIFF) maps on Carto?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, carto, import, facebook

My intuition is that the [maps that Facebook generated](https://dataforgood.fb.com/docs/facebook-data-for-good-publicly-available-data/) for most countries are most useful on interactive maps like Carto's, as the killer feature is the resolution for which you'd need to zoom in.

However, I am not familiar with GeoTIFF, let alone importing them to Carto.

What would be an example workflow if someone would like to see, say, [children under five of Hungary](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/hungary-high-resolution-population-density-maps-demographic-estimates) overlayed on a basemap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the CSVs first and look at it in QGIS
https://dataforgood.fb.com/docs/high-resolution-population-density-maps-demographic-estimates-documentation/#data-format
Then you can move on to GeoTiff which can also be viewed in QGIS. When you have that working you can export the data into a vector format like GeoJSON and use it in CartoDB or another web mapping platform.

Comment: Thanks, actually QGIS blows out of memory for me, it crashed after bloating to 59 GBs. Is there a simpler tool, maybe on the command line or something. Do I need more than a GeoTiff-GeoJSON conversion?

Comment: Yes try https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html You will need to know the values in the Geotiff file

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but now that installed `gdal` from `conda`, do I need more than a command like this `python gdal_polygonize.py HUN_women_of_reproductive_age_15_49.tif -f GeoJSON HUN_women_of_reproductive_age_15_49.json mothers`?

This produces a 350 MB large JSON file from 16.5 MB large TIFF, but Carto imports it as an empty layer.

Comment: OK, I still could not get QGIS to work, but friends could. Also, other tools that build on `gdal` worked for (the `rasterio` package for Python) even though `gdal` did not. Thanks!